# Is QTcpSocket stateChanged suitable for heart-beat check?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

If the client is been shutdowned, is the QTcpSocket will recvieve the stateChanged signal immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use client signal (disconnected()) at server side to receive the state change signal.

for example:

At Server side

```
connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(funcA())); 
//to recieve a signal immediately when client is shutdown

connect(client, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(funcB()));
// to recieve a signal immediately when client is connected
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I implemented this logic in my project, and it worked absolutely fine for me.

Comment: In the context of the Qt ecosystem, opting to use signal/slot mechanisms is the best way to proceed.  This method keeps your code nice and asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote end of a socket has been closed, it becomes readable and when reading from it you will receive zero bytes. Reading from a socket is the proper way to detect if the remote end has been closed gracefully.

So to answer your question, I'm guessing the the `stateChange` signal will *not* be called immediately when the remote end has been closed, as there is no way of knowing this until you try to read from the socket.